# Gridview button onclick not firing from a Microsoft Developer Network Example

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I created a simple Grid view with Multiple columns and add a button so when clicked pass the values of the row to a different webform but button on click not firing. I use the example code from the link 
: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626(v=vs.100).aspx

And this is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    PageSize="100" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <%--<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Edit" NavigateUrl="FormReport2.aspx" 
            Text="Edit" />--%>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" 
                CommandName="AddToCart" 
                CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"
                Text="Add to Cart" />
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="fldEmployeeID" HeaderText="EmployeeID" 
            SortExpression="fldEmployeeID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fldAbsentDate" HeaderText="AbsentDate" 
            SortExpression="fldAbsentDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fldAbsentCode" HeaderText="AbsentCode" 
            SortExpression="fldAbsentCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fldRuleViolationWarningType" 
            HeaderText="Rule Violation Warning Type" 
            SortExpression="fldRuleViolationWarningType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fldRuleViolationIssueDate" 
            HeaderText="Rule Violation Issue Date" 
            SortExpression="fldRuleViolationIssueDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fldLOAEndDate" HeaderText="LOA End Date" 
            SortExpression="fldLOAEndDate" />                                     

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code behind

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If (e.CommandName = "AddToCart") Then
        ' Retrieve the row index stored in the CommandArgument property.
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

        ' Retrieve the row that contains the button 
        ' from the Rows collection.
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)

        ' Add code here to add the item to the shopping cart.

    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be very appreciated. And also what would be the best way to pass the values from the row to a different web form from the code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to sing up for the event. See the last line here:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    PageSize="100" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
```

Comment: It is still not firing it. Any other ideas ?

Comment: @omachu23, nope, no more ideas, that should be it. How do you know it is not fired?

Comment: I created a textbox and before the if statement on the behind code wrote: Textbox1.Text = "its working" but nothing. I also set a break point but it gets never fires. DO you think a different way or achieving the same result. Thanks for your time Andrei

Comment: Your code works I did't realize that the OnRowCommand needed to be added to the GridView controller ! i was adding it to the button controller. thanks for the help. I would give you a vote up but not enough reputation point yet